# Mac terminal bash “command not found”

Tags: bash, shell

When I open iTerms,it shows:

```
-bash: AndroidStudioProjects: command not found
```

[image]

AndroidStudioProjects is a folder, I don't know what is causing this. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like something was added to your bash profile (`~/.bash_profile`) or your bash rc file (`~/.bash_rc`) or (`/etc/profile`)that should not be there anymore. Those files contain a sequence of commands that get executed either when a new bash session is started, or when a new terminal is opened.

I recommened examining both these files and looking for something related to the missing `AndroidStudioProjects` path. It was probably left over in one of the files.

P.S. It is possible that you may have only one of the files I mentioned. That is totally fine.